# Turning a JQuery plugin into an AngularJS Directive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, plugins

I'm new to the world of AngualrJS and was after an explanation of how to turn JQuery Slider plugin into a custom directive so that it functions in AngularJS

currently the jquery is trigger on the id 'camera-wrap'

```
<div id="camera_wrap" >
    .......image content etc.....
</div>
```

and then the function

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function startCamera() 
  { $('#camera_wrap').camera(
  { fx:'random', time: 2000, loader: 'none', playPause: false, height: '65%',
    pagination: true });   } $(function () { startCamera() });
 </script>
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks 
Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd probably just wrap it in a directive:

```
<div id="camera_wrap" camera-plugin>
```

And the directive

```
app.directive("cameraPlugin", [function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            $(elem).camera({ 
                fx:'random', 
                time: 2000, 
                loader: 'none', 
                playPause: false, 
                height: '65%',
                pagination: true 
            });

            startCamera(); //wherever this is defined?
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks, works like charm. And I understand it more so thanks again :)

Comment: Isnt wrapping jquery in a directive considered bad practice?

Comment: @britztopher -- jQuery in Angular in general is frowned upon, but there are some jQuery specific plugins - in which case I find it best to wrap them in a directive as it most likely deals with DOM manipulation.